# Does paypal resend IPN once a payment status has been changed from pending to complete/failed?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have done some scouring but cannot find a definitive answer for this!

I get "VERIFIED" and "Pending" so i can put my orders from "placed" to "in-progress" but need the complete / failed so i can then transfer to "paid" and "cancelled".

Anyone have anything definitive on this, or is it a waiting game until test payments are complete (not using sandbox).

Comment: exactly what I wanted to ask as well. couldn't find any discussion on this on paypal site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the payment has a “Pending” status, you receive another IPN when the payment clears, fails, or is denied.

Also, here are some good things to check once you receive Payment_staus=completed

- Check that the "txn_id" is not a duplicate to prevent a fraudster
  from using reusing an old, completed transaction
- Validate that the "receiver_email" is an email address registered in
  your PayPal account, to prevent the payment from being sent to a
  fraudster's account
- Check other transaction details such as the item number and price to
  confirm that the price has not been changed

Comment: 1. If the payment status is 'completed' why do you need to confirm that the payment status is 'completed'? 2. The transaction ID *is* a duplicate: that's how you know what transaction has been completed.

Comment: It is the same Transaction ID as pending, but you should not have duplicate transaction IDs for completed orders. As listed above, you want to make sure it is not a duplicate of an old completed transaction. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: As I understand it, you should not have duplicate {transaction ID, payment status} *pairs.* You haven't answered (1).

Comment: @EJP You cannot assume that there will not be a duplicate. Paypal reattempts failed IPNs. Sometimes Paypal will resend IPNs when it believes that last attempt failed. This could be because of network error and totally outside your control. Paypal documentation clearly says that you should do that this check to make sure you don't process an order twice.

Answer (score 0):

You get another IPN (*not* a 'resend'), same txn_id, with payment_status='Completed'.